# Navbar Dropdown functionality

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive

I have a Navbar and it works fine. The only issue I have is when on mobile I want the drop downs to simply drop down as they are supposed to . But on a computer I want it to drop down on hover(it already does) but send them to a link if clicked. My current dilemma is when on mobile or tablet and they click on the drop down it will send them to the link instead of activating the drop down menu. I'm not too familiar with Javascript so i'm not sure if that's the answer to this but the codepen is this https://codepen.io/Religion/pen/BajmQMz

This is my code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #60b4df;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

section{
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
    width: 100%;
    background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat top center / cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(56, 165, 238, 0.5);
}

.container{
    max-width: 65rem;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.logo-container{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-btn{
    flex: 3;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-links{
    flex: 2;
}

.log-sign{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
}

.logo{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 3rem;
}

.logo span{
    font-weight: 300;
}

.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5rem 1.3rem;
    font-size: .8rem;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 .2rem;
    transition: .3s;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn.solid, .btn.transparent:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #69bde7;
}

.btn.transparent, .btn.solid:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-links > ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-link{
    position: relative;
}

.nav-link > a{
    line-height: 3rem;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 .8rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: .95rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: .5s;
}

.nav-link > a > i{
    margin-left: .2rem;
}

.nav-link:hover > a{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.dropdown{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 10rem;
    transform: translateY(10px);
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
}

.dropdown ul{
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-link > a{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    font-size: .9rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: .3s;
}

.dropdown-link:hover > a{
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-link:not(:nth-last-child(2)){
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.dropdown-link i{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.arrow{
    position: absolute;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    top: -5.5px;
    left: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
    z-index: -1;
}

.dropdown-link:first-child:hover ~ .arrow{
    background-color: #3498db;
}

.dropdown-link{
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown.second{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    padding-left: .8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateX(10px);
}

.dropdown.second .arrow{
    top: 10px;
    left: -5.5px;
}

.nav-link:hover > .dropdown,
.dropdown-link:hover > .dropdown{
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.hamburger-menu-container{
    flex: 1;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.hamburger-menu{
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.hamburger-menu div{
    width: 1.6rem;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1001;
    transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger-menu div:before,
.hamburger-menu div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger-menu div:before{
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}

.hamburger-menu div:after{
    transform: translateY(7px);
}

#check{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1.5rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    z-index: 90000;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

#check:checked ~ .hamburger-menu-container .hamburger-menu div{
    background-color: transparent;
}

#check:checked ~ .hamburger-menu-container .hamburger-menu div:before{
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

#check:checked ~ .hamburger-menu-container .hamburger-menu div:after{
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(15px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 920px){
    .hamburger-menu-container{
        display: flex;
    }

    #check{
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-btn{
        position: fixed;
        height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
        top: 3rem;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #69bde7;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: .65s;
    }

    #check:checked ~ .nav-btn{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    #check:checked ~ .nav-btn .nav-link,
    #check:checked ~ .nav-btn .log-sign{
        animation: animation .5s ease forwards var(--i);
    }

    .nav-links{
        flex: initial;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav-links > ul{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .nav-link{
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(15px);
    }

    .nav-link > a{
        line-height: 1;
        padding: 1.6rem 2rem;
    }

    .nav-link:hover > a{
        transform: scale(1);
        background-color: #50a9d6;
    }

    .dropdown, .dropdown.second{
        position: initial;
        top: initial;
        left: initial;
        transform: initial;
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #3183ac;
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover > .dropdown,
    .dropdown-link:hover > .dropdown{
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-link:hover > a > i,
    .dropdown-link:hover > a > i{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    .dropdown-link > a{
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 1.2rem 2rem;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    .dropdown.second .dropdown-link > a{
        padding: 1.2rem 2rem 1.2rem 3rem;
    }

    .dropdown.second .dropdown.second .dropdown-link > a{
        padding: 1.2rem 2rem 1.2rem 4rem;
    }

    .dropdown-link:not(:nth-last-child(2)){
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    .arrow{
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #69bde7;
        left: 10%;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(45deg);
        transition: .5s;
    }

    .nav-link:hover .arrow{
        background-color: #50a9d6;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown .arrow{
        display: none;
    }

    .dropdown-link:hover > a{
        background-color: #3a91bd;
    }

    .dropdown-link:first-child:hover ~ .arrow{
        background-color: #50a9d6;
    }

    .nav-link > a > i{
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transition: .7s;
    }

    .dropdown i{
        font-size: 1rem;
        transition: .7s;
    }

    .log-sign{
        flex: initial;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1.5rem 1.9rem;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(15px);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
        <div class ="container-nav">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="check">
            
            <div class="logo-container">
                <h3 class="logo">David's<span> Dental</span></a></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-btn">
                <div class="nav-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-link" style="--i: .6s">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link" style="--i: .85s">
                            <a href="{% url 'PatientInfo' %}">Patient Information<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'visit' %}">First Dental Visit</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'NewPatient' %}">New Patients</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'checkup' %}">Check Ups</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'payment' %}">Insurance and Financial Information</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'COVID' %}">COVID-19 Office Re-opening</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'PatientReviews' %}">Patient Reviews</a>
                                    </li>

                                        
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link" style="--i: 1.1s">
                            <a href="{% url 'service' %}">Services<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'cosmeticdentistry' %}">Cosmetic Dentistry<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                        <div class="dropdown second">
                                         <ul>
                                                <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'DentalBondings' %}">Dental Bonding</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'Clearbraces' %}">Clear Braces</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'Porcelainveneers' %}">Porcelain Veneers</a>
                                                </li>
                                                 <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'inlaysonlays' %}">Inlays & Onlays</a>
                                                </li>
                                                 <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'TeethWhitening' %}">Teeth Whitening</a>
                                                </li>
                                          </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'Restorativedentistry' %}">Restorative Dentistry<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                        <div class="dropdown second">
                                         <ul>
                                                <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'DentalFillings' %}">Dental Fillings</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'DentalBridges' %}">Dental Bridges</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'DentalCrowns' %}">Dental Crowns</a>
                                                </li>
                                                 <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'Rootcanal' %}">Root Canal</a>
                                                </li>
                                                 <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'DentalImplants' %}">Dental Implants<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                                    <div class="dropdown second">
                                                      <ul>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'Replacemissing' %}">Replace Missing Teeth</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'Overviewimplants' %}">Overview Of Implant Placement</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'missingupperor' %}">Missing all Upper or Lower Teeth</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                         <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'BoneGrafting' %}">Bone Grafting for Implants</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'Teeth_in_a_day' %}">Teeth-in-a-day</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'AfterImplantP' %}">After Implant Placement</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'CostDental' %}">Cost of Dental Implants</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                         <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'DentalFAQs' %}">
                                                            Dental Implants FAQs</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                      </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                 <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'Dentures' %}">Dentures<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                                    <div class="dropdown second">
                                                      <ul>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'ImmediateDentures' %}">Immediate Dentures</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'PartialDentures' %}">Partial Dentures</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        
                                                         
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'ExamsMaintenance' %}">Exams & Maintenance</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'DentalRelines' %}">Denture Relines</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'Softliners' %}">Soft Liners</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                         
                                                      </ul>
                                                </li>
                                          </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                            
                                    
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link" style="--i: 1.35s">
                            <a href="{% url 'examcheckup' %}">Preventive Care<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'examcheckup' %}">Dental Exams & Checkups</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'Hygiene' %}">Oral Hygiene</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'ChildDentistry' %}">Child Dentistry</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'Teethcleaning' %}">Teeth Cleaning</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'Teethcleaning' %}">Wisdom Teeth Removal</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-link">
                                        <a href="{% url 'Periodontal' %}">Gum Disease Treatment<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                         <div class="dropdown second">
                                          <ul>
                                              <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                <a href="{% url 'Periodontal' %}">Periodontal Maintenance</a>
                                              </li>
                                              <li class="dropdown-link">
                                                  <a href="{% url 'Deepteeth' %}">Deep Teeth Cleaning</a>
                                              </li>
                                              </li>

                                             </ul>
                                              </div>
                                          </ul>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                            <li class="nav-link" style="--i: 1.35s">
                            <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link" style="--i: 1.35s">
                            <a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                
            </div>

            <div class="hamburger-menu-container">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  </body
```

Comment: So the Problem is When on Mobile devices the dropdown doesn't work ?

Comment: yea it doesnt drop down if clicked, it goes to the link . The Only way the drop down works is if it doesnt have any link

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you click something it only does one thing:

a) Send them to a link `<a href="/link.html">link</a>`

b) Javascript that will display the drop down.

Can't do both since it doesn't know what you mean when you click.

Suggestion:  Have an arrow beside the link.  The arrow expands or contracts the menu.  The text is the link.

Ex
[HOME > ]

`HOME` on click, go to  link

`>` on click, expand menu.

Because your menus are supposed to behave differently based on screen size, you may need @media settings.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp